# real time global change for environment variables PATH

Tags: environment-variables, path

What is the best way to modify `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that it has a **real time** affect for any logged in user that does **new terminal window** in runlevel 5 {graphical.target}?

This is on RHEL/CentOS 7.6 (and later).

Also, what is the proper way to `source /opt/intel/compilervars.sh` ?  Where should this *source* statement happen so that it's modifications are **automatically in  affect** for any logged in user ?

I want no duplicates in `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-environment-variables-of-another-process-in-unix) or google `write to /proc environ`. The short answer to your question is `you cannot change another process's PATH`